# elasticsearch update doc very slow

Tags: elasticsearch

Now it even takes about 7 minutes to update a doc.

Elasticsearch version: 6.8.6

Deploy via docker

Single node, heap size: 8G, 30 shards, a total of 6.2G data, 2 million doc. This is too slow, if anyone can tell me how to solve it, I would appreciate it

iostat info

```
Linux 4.15.0-20-generic (max-master)    12/18/2020  _x86_64_    (32 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          15.46    0.00    8.95    0.09    0.00   75.51

Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
sda             222.31        92.21      5448.83   23575235 1393042693
```

cat _nodes/hot_threads

```
::: {es-node1}{VxAcSdn8QJKRBu705pFVDA}{ozapTgHcRDaIgu9Cb-tB9w}{10.244.0.19}{10.244.0.19:9300}{ml.machine_memory=66933485568, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true}
   Hot threads at 2020-12-18T08:36:29.005Z, interval=500ms, busiestThreads=3, ignoreIdleThreads=true:
   
   100.4% (502ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[es-node1][write][T#7]'
     2/10 snapshots sharing following 205 elements
       ...
22.7% (113.6ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[es-node1][write][T#4]'
     6/10 snapshots sharing following 192 elements
       ...
```

cat /_nodes/stats/thread_pool?human&pretty

```
{
  "_nodes": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "cluster_name": "zs",
  "nodes": {
    "VxAcSdn8QJKRBDA": {
      "timestamp": 1608280589005,
      "name": "es-node1",
      "transport_address": "10.44.0.19:9300",
      "host": "10.44.0.19",
      "ip": "10.44.0.19:9300",
      "roles": [
        "master",
        "data",
        "ingest"
      ],
      "attributes": {
        "ml.machine_memory": "66933485568",
        "xpack.installed": "true",
        "ml.max_open_jobs": "20",
        "ml.enabled": "true"
      },
      "thread_pool": {
        "analyze": {
          "threads": 0,
          "queue": 0,
          "active": 0,
          "rejected": 0,
          "largest": 0,
          "completed": 0
        },
        "ccr": {
          "threads": 0,
          "queue": 0,
          "active": 0,
          "rejected": 0,
          "largest": 0,
          "completed": 0
        },
        "fetch_shard_started": {
          "threads": 1,
          "queue": 0,
          "active": 0,
          "rejected": 0,
          "largest": 16,
          "completed": 167
        },
        "fetch_shard_store": {
          "threads": 0,
          "queue": 0,
          "active": 0,
          "rejected": 0,
          "largest": 0,
          "completed": 0
        },
        "flush": {
          "threads": 1,
          "queue": 0,
          "active": 0,
          "rejected": 0,
          "largest": 4,
          "completed": 368
        },
        "force_merge": {
          "threads": 0,
          "queue": 0,
          "active": 0,
          "rejected": 0,
          "largest": 0,
          "completed": 0
        },
        "generic": {
          "threads": 24,
          "queue": 0,
          "active": 1,
          "rejected": 0,
          "largest": 24,
          "completed": 10495
        },
        "get": {
          "threads": 8,
          "queue": 0,
          "active": 0,
          "rejected": 0,
          "largest": 8,
          "completed": 389
        },
        "index": {
          "threads": 0,
          "queue": 0,
          "active": 0,
          "rejected": 0,
          "largest": 0,
          "completed": 0
        },
        "listener": {
          "threads": 3,
          "queue": 0,
          "active": 0,
          "rejected": 0,
          "largest": 3,
          "completed": 3
        },
        "management": {
          "threads": 5,
          "queue": 0,
          "active": 2,
          "rejected": 0,
          "largest": 5,
          "completed": 7194
        },
        "ml_autodetect": {
          "threads": 0,
          "queue": 0,
          "active": 0,
          "rejected": 0,
          "largest": 0,
          "completed": 0
        },
        "ml_datafeed": {
          "threads": 0,
          "queue": 0,
          "active": 0,
          "rejected": 0,
          "largest": 0,
          "completed": 0
        },
        "ml_utility": {
          "threads": 1,
          "queue": 0,
          "active": 0,
          "rejected": 0,
          "largest": 1,
          "completed": 1
        },
        "refresh": {
          "threads": 4,
          "queue": 0,
          "active": 0,
          "rejected": 0,
          "largest": 4,
          "completed": 51313
        },
        "rollup_indexing": {
          "threads": 0,
          "queue": 0,
          "active": 0,
          "rejected": 0,
          "largest": 0,
          "completed": 0
        },
        "search": {
          "threads": 13,
          "queue": 0,
          "active": 1,
          "rejected": 0,
          "largest": 13,
          "completed": 217319
        },
        "search_throttled": {
          "threads": 0,
          "queue": 0,
          "active": 0,
          "rejected": 0,
          "largest": 0,
          "completed": 0
        },
        "security-token-key": {
          "threads": 0,
          "queue": 0,
          "active": 0,
          "rejected": 0,
          "largest": 0,
          "completed": 0
        },
        "snapshot": {
          "threads": 0,
          "queue": 0,
          "active": 0,
          "rejected": 0,
          "largest": 0,
          "completed": 0
        },
        "warmer": {
          "threads": 4,
          "queue": 0,
          "active": 0,
          "rejected": 0,
          "largest": 4,
          "completed": 399
        },
        "watcher": {
          "threads": 0,
          "queue": 0,
          "active": 0,
          "rejected": 0,
          "largest": 0,
          "completed": 0
        },
        "write": {
          "threads": 8,
          "queue": 0,
          "active": 6,
          "rejected": 0,
          "largest": 8,
          "completed": 1401
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you doing force_merge after updating this document?
Can you share how you are updating this doc, and its size

Comment: I didn't call force merge, I just used the bulkservice method in elastic.v5 pkg in golang. To facilitate debugging, there is only one update in bulk. one doc size is 10KB

Comment: I think the bulk might be comitting the entire index by default (I don't know for sure). Can you add a link to the pkg in the question?

Comment: This is the link of pkg：https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v5#BulkService